# Strong operator topology on a $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

As far as I know, the Strong Operator Topology (SOT) is defined for the space of operators $B(H)$ for any  Hilbert space H. The paper I am reading implicitly make references to the 'fact' that we can endow any $C^*$-algebra $A$ with the strong operator topology. How do we do that? The most natural way that I can think of is the topology induced by the Gelfand-Naimark-Segal theorem. Suppose that $\pi: A\to B(H)$ is the representation that realizes $A$ as an operator algebra (by GNS), do we define the strong operator open sets in $A$ via inverse images $\pi^{-1}(V)$ where $V\subseteq B(H)$ is strong operator open in $B(H)$?

Comment: Your guess makes sense to me. Although, keep in mind that different faithful representations might induce different topologies, check this out:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930886/dependence-of-operator-topologies-in-a-c-algebra-on-the-representation

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no "the"  representation that makes $A$ an operator algebra. As mentioned by @JustDroppedIn, [there are usually different representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930886/dependence-of-operator-topologies-in-a-c-algebra-on-the-representation).